# Node.js Parallel Post Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing, requestjs

I have a large .txt file that contains user id's of my website. Example:

```
10929
10299
01021
39100
23841
```

The txt file has more than 10k id's.

Would it be possible to read all of the .txt content and send 100 requests (each request a different id) around 1 second so that my api can check the integrity of these id's?

Request example:

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.mywebsite.com/mobile_authentications',
    headers: {
        'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR',
        'X-Client-Info': 'Timezone%3D-Infinity%26device_id%3D578e4ac016b69248%26utc_offset%3D-0300%26app_id%3D7092%26resolution%3D720x1280%26connectivity%3DWIFI%26site_id%3DMLB%26density%3D320%26user_id%3Dguest'
    },
    body: '{"authentication_request":{"client_id":"USER ID HERE"}}',
};
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    throw error
});
```

I've tried in many ways, with loops and with multithreaded modules but I did not succeed.

Thanks.

Comment: The rate-limiting of the service that you are presumably trying to brute-force will throw you out.

Comment: Of course it's possible to send multiple requests, in parallel, to an API; but, obviously it depends on restrictions placed by the API implementer.

Comment: But your snippet doesn't show how you are iterating over the ids.

Comment: The API I am referring to is mine. There are no limits of requests. I just want to send multiple simultaneous requests to my API using requests module. Thank you all

Comment: You can use `Promise.all` to achieve parallel-like requests. Since XHR requests are asynchronous by nature, executuon will be fast

Comment: @molamk, How can I create multiple requests with different id's? In other words, each line of a txt would be a new request.

Comment: Can you read your file and convert it to an array of IDs?

Comment: @molamk, Yes. Look: ```var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var request = require("request");

var filename = process.argv[2];
readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(filename),
    terminal: false
}).on('line', function(line) {
var id = line;
});```